# how to reach the epoch number in which the early stopping criteria is met

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I use callbacks to stop the training process if certain criteria are met. I was wondering how I can access the epoch number in which the training is stopped due to the callback.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 


class stopAtLossValue(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            eps = 0.01 
           
            if logs.get('loss') <= eps:
                 self.model.stop_training = True
                    
training_input=  np.random.random ([30,10])
training_output = np.random.random ([30,1])



model = tf.keras.Sequential([  
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(10,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(15,activation=tf.keras.activations.linear),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) 
])   
                               
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01))

hist = model.fit(training_input, training_output, epochs=100, batch_size=100,  verbose=1, callbacks=[stopAtLossValue()])
```

For this example, my training is completed at the 66th epoch since the loss is under 0.01.

```
Epoch 66/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0099
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be to get the length of the `history.history` object:

```
len(model.history.history['loss'])
```

The more intricate way would be to get the number of iterations from the optimizer:

```
model.optimizer._iterations
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get epoch number in callback, you should use `on_epoch_end` function instead of `on_batch_end`. See the below code for callback function

```py
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    eps = 0.01 
    print(epoch) # This will print the number of epoch
    if logs.get('loss') <= eps:
          self.model.stop_training = True
```